# Multiple rows with same ID number but different status values - How do I select out specific statuses to grab IDs

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregation

I have a table with an ID field and a status field that can have multiple status types such as "active" "finaled" "fail" "comments". I'd like to be able to select out permit numbers where they do not have a "finaled" status tied to a permit number or, do not have at least four "active" statuses. I know I need to use COUNT() but I can't figure out how to have it filter by permit number.

Example of the table where permitnum 777 would be flagged in the end:

```
PermitNum Status  
222       active  
222       active  
222       finaled  
444       active  
444       active  
444       active  
444       active  
777       active  
777       fail  
777       active  
777       active
```

I've been using COUNT() to get a generalized count of the status field based on a WHERE clause but I don't know how to tie it to the permit number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation.  To get the values being flagged:

```
select permitno
from t
group by permitno
having sum(case when status = 'finaled' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when status = 'active' then 1 else 0 end) < 4;
```

To get the "good" permits:

```
select permitno
from t
group by permitno
having sum(case when status = 'finaled' then 1 else 0 end) = 0 or
       sum(case when status = 'active' then 1 else 0 end) >= 4;
```

Comment: According to the OP, you need to change the first `HAVING` clause to `status = 'finaled'` not `failed`. Otherwise, I think your second query is correct.

Comment: This is great, an initial test is working correctly. Thank you Gordon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists` and restrict by `having count(case when Status='active' then 1 end)<4` for your next condition :

```
select PermitNum 
  from tab t
 where not exists ( select 0 from tab where status='finaled' and PermitNum = t.PermitNum  )
 group by PermitNum
having count(case when Status='active' then 1 end)<4
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=6a1171e6442570dac41dc5f0c975dcd5)</kbd>